# how can i fake an url with regex with Http client in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mocking

i was following the docs from laravel to mockup the Http responses from an API, so i'm using this code to fake the responses

```php
Http::fake([
    // Stub a string response for Google endpoints...
    'google.com/*' => Http::response('Hello World', 200, ['Headers']),
]);
```

but i need to mockup a general url

`https://example.com/categories/{id}/products`

so i try this but, doesn't works

```php
Http::fake([
    // Stub a JSON response for GitHub endpoints...
    'https://example.com/categories/*/products' => Http::response(['foo' => 'bar'], 200, ['Headers'])
]);
```

how can i make the url regex to catch all the ids?

Comment: I am not sure that's possible, unless you loop over every product and generate the URL with the id. Another way would be to stub all requests to `https://example.com/categories/*` if you don't have other requests that call `categories/*` that should return something different.

Comment: i think in that, fake every url with a loop, but i'ts too much, already i have mocking 10 url, so i have these urls `https://example.com/categories/{id}/products` and `https://example.com/categories/{id}/brands`, so it's not possible just use `https://example.com/categories/*`

Comment: Sounds to me like you are testing too many things in this test, could you not split the tests into multiple simpler tests? Why are you testing multiple products anyway, is one product not enough?

Comment: it's not a laravel app, it's a laravel package, this package have options to change fake data url or use the real api, so i want to make when change to testing, it can response every request with an example

every response return a .json file content example

Comment: Can you show more code, should be possible to mock or arrange data to fix the url to something predictable